# To carry out CRUD operations for multiple tables in a single view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm on Laravel 8 with Livewire, currently have 3 models, `Category`, `SubCategory` and `MenuItem` for 3 tables. All the above models have separate livewire controllers and have the code for the CRUD operations respectively. I have separate views and routes to edit the above tables and they all have a eloquent relationship between each other. Now what I need to do here to is, I need to display all the three tables in a single view to carry out the CRUD operations.

I tried to achieve this by using the sub-view function, to pass the view and make the variables available to the specific view, but it didn't work out and I think it isn't the way to do it, was just trying to figure a workaround. I'm mentioning my models down below for referencing. Please help me with this. Thanks a lot for your time!

App\Models\Category

```
class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "categories";
    protected $fillable = ['sub_category_name'];

    public function SubCategories() {
        return $this->hasMany(SubCategory::class, 'category_id');
    }

    public function MenuItems() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'MenuItem::class',
            'SubCategory::class',
            'sub_category_id',
            'category_id'
        );
    }
}
```

App\Models\SubCategory

```
class SubCategory extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "sub_categories";
    protected $fillable = ['category_id', 'sub_category_name'];

    public function Categories() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
    }

    public function MenuItems() {
        return $this->hasMany(MenuItem::class, 'sub_category_id');
    }
}
```

App\Models\MenuItem

```
class MenuItem extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "menu_items";
    protected $fillable = ['sub_category_id', 'item_name', 'item_description'];

    public function SubCategories() {
        return $this->belongsTo(SubCategory::class, 'sub_category_id');
    }
}
```

This is what I tried to achieve the said result. As I needed to include the view with the sub category table to the menu items table view. I made the variables available to that specific view.

Resources\Views\Livewire\Menu-Item

```
<div>
    @include('livewire.sub-category')
</div>
```

App\Providers\AppServiceProvider

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use App\Models\SubCategory;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider

    {
        /**
         * Register any application services.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function register()
        {
            //
        }
    
        /**
         * Bootstrap any application services.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function boot()
        {
            View::composer('livewire.menu-item', function ($view) {
                $view::with('sub_category_name', SubCategory::orderBy('sub_category_name')->get());
            });
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: so what you have tried so far .? any error ?

Comment: @KamleshPaul No mate, no error, just unable to do it, as I tried to output the other two tables (by sub view as well as, by creating the other two tables with the concerned variables) in a single view, and tried using view composer to make the variables available to the specific view, but it was unable to get the variables which were defined in the controller itself, so no output.

Comment: add those code as well

Comment: @KamleshPaul Its not possible by the approach which I was using so its not  useful, I guess. I was using sub-view to make the view available from one view to another.

Comment: you should add your code so we can understand better and if you are seeking for any recommendation this is not the right place to ask

Comment: @KamleshPaul Here you go mate! Just check the question, I have updated it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223133/discussion-between-toxifiedhashkey-and-kamlesh-paul).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the above problem, using livewire's component feature. Created 3 separate component for 3 separate tables, and finally used all the three components in the `master-menu.blade.php` file. Working with livewire and laravel is a treat.